# Did Victor Hess discover cosmic rays directly, or muons with his gold-leaf electroscope?

Tags: particle-physics, electricity, atmospheric-science, history, cosmic-rays

Most histories just mention cosmic rays themselves, but I also read that cosmic rays themselves rarely make it far into Earth's atmosphere, and it is usually muons, (or tauons or electrons) detected by simple electric-charge detectors like Hess's gold-leaf spectroscopy...

Comment: Playing with the defintion of the word "cosmic". If one accept that "cosmocs" is everhthing outside the earth,  space, then muons  are cosmic. If cosmos is the universe  excluding the solar system then only the very high energy showers are cosmic.

Answer (score 3):

At the [lower levels < 5 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_ray) Hess ballooned to, he observed [secondary air showers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_shower_(physics)), so, then, electrons, pions  (→ muons, ionizing γs) etc... copiously produced by the blocked primaries (mostly protons and nuclei):
[image]

So, then, he discovered them *indirectly*, but what of it?